# Restrict EditText programatically to show numeric keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

There is no XML associated with this EditText. It's generated in the Activity.

```
final EditText txtPrice = new EditText(getContext());
txtPrice.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, false));
txtPrice.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(3) });
```

This is okay, but not ideal. I want to show the Android numeric keyboard, to really simplify things.

How do I call that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set your `EditText` input type

```
final EditText txtPrice = new EditText(getContext());
txtPrice.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

This will restrict its inputs to be numbers only, and thus, Android will automatically show only the numeric keyboard.